# Compile a C++ program with only dependency on kernel32.dll and user32.dll?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, runtime

I'm working with Visual Studio 2005.

I want to compile a simple program that will work with any Windows 32bit version independent of what c++ runtime library version installed.

This program will call to `GetModuleHandle` and `GetProcAddress` functions without any other function calls, and then exit, when the exit code is the function address.

How to compile a C++ program with only dependency on kernel32.dll and user32.dll, without any c++ runtime library?

Comment: +1 This is the epitome of a good SO question.

Comment: What's the purpose of this program, if I may ask?

Comment: I'm implementing code injection from a 64 bit process to 32 bit process, and I need helper 32 bit program to find address of some functions.

Comment: Maybe you should have asked that question instead, because there are much better ways of doing it than creating a helper program. In my own open-source project (check my profile), I have 64-bit to 32-bit DLL injection, and for this I need to retrieve the address of the 32-bit LoadLibrary. All you have to do is to map in the DLL yourself and lookup the function address, then add the base address of the DLL as loaded by the remote process.

Answer (score 6):

You'll need to define your own entry point instead of using `main` or `WinMain`. Your entry point is a void function taking no arguments. You have to specify its name to the linker with `/entry:funcName` (where `funcName` gets replaced by whatever name you gave the function you want to use as the entry point).

When you do this you'll also have to specify the subsystem to the linker, as in `/subsystem:console`. It normally deduces the subsystem based on the name of function it finds (i.e., `main` -> console, `WinMain` -> Windows), but when you use your own entry point, you have to specify it explicitly. Although you probably don't want to very often, you can specify the subsystem explicitly even when you don't specify your own entry point, so (for example) you can use `main` as the entry point to a windows subsystem program, or `WinMain` as the entry point to a console program.

Comment: Also, the entry point must be declared `APIENTRY` (== `__stdcall`), and you need to use `ExitProcess()` instead of returning from it.

Comment: @Brian: That's not what MSDN says about the return value --http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f9t8842e(v=VS.80).aspx

Comment: @Brian: Returning from it works fine. I normally don't declare it with `APIENTRY` or `__stdcall` either -- I just compile with `/Gz`. OTOH, what you're advising probably is *better* even if it's not really necessary.

Comment: @Ben and @Jerry :-) – Hmmm, interesting.  Just tried it on Windows XP and the loader does indeed clean up after you if you fall off the end of your entry point.  Not really surprising, of course.  I vaguely remember bad things happening in earlier versions of Windows if you didn't call `ExitProcess()` explicitly, but I'm not too sure any more and I haven't got an old system handy to check.  I rather suspect it's just one of those things that I've always done simply because I didn't know any better...

Comment: @Brian: I'm pretty sure it "falling" off the end worked fine back to at least NT 3.5. Might have caused a problem with something like Windows 95 or Win32S though -- I'm not sure.

Comment: @JC: Windows only terminates a process when there are no active threads. Falling out the bottom of the EXE entrypoint closes that thread. If you have called any API that creates worker threads then the app will never terminate unless the API provides a way to cleanup the worker threads.

Comment: @BrianNixon: Brian Nixon who used to work at cueSim? Small world! Thanks for the help here, hope you're doing okay (Ian H).

Answer (score 5):

Set `/NODEFAULTLIB` under your project options.  In newer versions of Visual C++, you'll also have to turn off stack overrun checks, because those cause the compiler to automatically insert calls to library functions.

EDIT: If you really mean "run on ANY 32-bit Windows version", you're also going to have to use `editbin` to change the subsystem version field in the PE header.  Otherwise you're restricted to (IIRC) Windows 2000 and later when building with the VC++ 2005 linker, and newer versions of VC++ are even worse (requiring XP by default).  Windows 2000 is 5.0, you'd want to specify 3.5 or thereabouts to allow all versions of NT in addition to Win9x.

Comment: While you do want to specify `/nodefaultlib`, but itself it'll just give you `unresolved external` errors. The real key is using your own entry point to eliminate dependencies on the library.

Comment: @Jerry: I guess you could name your entry-point according to whatever the linker looks for by default (`wCRTWinMain` or suchlike), but I agree that using `/entry` is cleaner.

Comment: I've never tried that, so I suppose it might work, but can't say for sure (without testing, it's hard to say what magic the linker might use/invoke/depend on). Regardless of whether you use `/entry:` to specify what it is, however, you'll have to define the entry point anyway.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>I'm not sure why everyone's advising against using the standard library</strike>. This method assumes you want your code to run on Windows 2000 or later and don't mind losing support for Win 9x. You can still use the C/C++ standard library - You can use the `/MT` option in your project's C/C++ Code Generation pages, which will link in the standard library statically.

However, two notes, the first from me: the idea of having a dynamically linked standard library is that any bugs in it will get patched by Windows Update (in theory). If you link the library in statically, you need to redistribute your application to fix standard library bugs. So **it isn't advised.**

Secondly, from the MSDN article on [compiler options](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2kzt1wy3%28v=vs.71%29.aspx):

> **Caution**   Do not mix static and
>   dynamic versions of the run-time
>   libraries. Having more than one copy
>   of the run-time libraries in a process
>   can cause problems, because static
>   data in one copy is not shared with
>   the other copy. The linker prevents
>   you from linking with both static and
>   dynamic versions within one .exe file,
>   but you can still end up with two (or
>   more) copies of the run-time
>   libraries. For example, a dynamic-link
>   library linked with the static
>   (non-DLL) versions of the run-time
>   libraries can cause problems when used
>   with an .exe file that was linked with
>   the dynamic (DLL) version of the
>   run-time libraries. (You should also
>   avoid mixing the debug and non-debug
>   versions of the libraries in one
>   process.)

In short, doing this can cause confusion if you try to build in other components linked against a dynamically-linked standard library.

Of course, the other downside is that this will make your executable larger, too.

Edit: the result, under depends.exe, looks like this: (of course, I'm using 64-bit Windows, which is only available for XP and later... if you want to know what this looks like on 32-bit windows, imagine if the `64`s weren't there!).

[image: depends.exe program showing only one dynamic dependency, kernel32.dll]

Comment: "I'm not sure why everyone's advising against using the standard library." Yes, that was exactly what I was thinking. +1.

Comment: I'm glad it wasn't just me. I also tried it using `depends.exe` profiler to make sure the standard libs aren't being dynamically called. Just in case.

Comment: Maybe because the standard library depends on functions introduced in a particular version of Windows, which contradicts the requirements of the question.  And the question also said "without any C++ runtime library".

Comment: I could be wrong, perhaps I am, but I thought he meant no dynamic dependence on say `MSVCP80.DLL`. And are the standard libraries really dependent on which version of windows you're using?

Comment: @Ninefingers: Yeah, the VS2005 standard library initialization code calls some function that was introduced in Win2000.  If you go back to Dependency Walker and expand the import list you can probably figure out which one, `GetProcessorFeature` or something like that, I've forgotten (hint: Dependency Walker has a toolbar button for calling up function help in MSDN, although I don't know if MSDN even has information going back farther than Win2000 any more).

Comment: @ninefingers: Of course you should use a 32-bit compiler and 32-bit Dependency Walker if you're going to do that test, 64-bit code of course requires WinXP or later.

Comment: @BenVoigt ah of course. I was thinking Win 2000 and older. Shouldn't make assumptions. Well, I'll leave this here after an edit or two for posterity.

Comment: @wj32: We advised that because it was exactly what he asked for: "How to compile a C++ program with only dependency on kernel32.dll and user32.dll, without any c++ runtime library?"

Comment: @Jerry Coffin: It's a bit ambiguous, because by "dependency" I was thinking in terms of what functions it imports. If you statically link the CRT it's not a "dependency" in my interpretation of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Check the tiny c libs. Also statically link.

Comment: Technically it is an answer as he is making a suggestion that may be what DxCK needs to get started/finish his project.  However it could do with fleshing out.

Answer (score 0):

You actually don't need User32.dll either, the only ones you truly cannot remove are Kernel32.dll and Ntdll.dll - those are injected into your process space by PsCreateProcess (i.e. the kernel half of how the kernel creates a new process).

Comment: No, kernel32 is not mapped in by "PsCreateProcess", which by the way does not exist. kernel32 is loaded by LdrpInitializeProcess in ntdll, in user-mode. The only DLL which you can't remove is ntdll.

Comment: Maybe that should be PspCreateProcess, which is why it "doesn't exist". Oh well.